# How to Load embedded Crystal Report after Deployment

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, deployment, crystal-reports

I am developing a WinForms C# application using Visual Studio 2019 that uses Crystal Reports.

I am using the following code to load the report, it uses the path of crystal report file:

```
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
cryRpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\CrystalReport1.rpt");
```

After the deployment this produces an error that **the File is not found in the specified path**

The Crystal report file is actually embedded,

how can I access the embedded report after deployment?

Comment: include the item as content

Comment: How can I include the item as content?

Comment: see answer below

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark the reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue. If you still have questions, you can reply to me and I will help you through it.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure the file is set to

Build Action >> Content;
Copy to Output Directory >> Copy always